# Making a subpart of the html scrollable

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a 3 column layout as drawn here:
[image: Mockup]

The second and third column are within an iframe as this outer navigation is used on other pages and I wanted to avoid duplicate code. So there is a first website containing the left column  + an iframe.
The second page (source of the iframe) contains the other 2 columns. Both times this is done by float.
My problem is, that it can happen that there are too many attributes so that it doesn't fit on the screen so I would like to make only that part scrollable. At the moment the right column is a div element and contains a table. The first row contains the "Outline" text and the second a div with the attribute-value thing. I tried getting the scrollable by setting overflow: scroll on the wrapper div (of the table).
This does not work and the table (the one being the third column) is actually higher than the parent div element (I have set the height of the table to 100%)

Can anyone give an example on how to structure such a case? Or even tell me where my mistake is?

Thanks

Comment: What about `position:fixed` for the first two rows?

Comment: I want to position it relative to the parent, so the first row(Outline) should fill the whole row and the second (attributes) should fill the whole second row.
But my problem is, that the table is higher than the div in which it is

Answer (score 0):

To give anything a height of 100% (of its parent), the parent's height must be specified. The parent of the right column is the body, thus give the body a height of 100%. Then this should be easy enough to solve:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#elementCol {
    float: left;
    background: orange;
}
#attribCol {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div id="elementCol">
    <p>Element 1</p>
    <p>Element 2</p>
</div>
<div id="attribCol">
    <p>Outline</p>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Attribute 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Attribute 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Attribute 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Attribute 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Attribute 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Attribute 6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Attribute 7</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Attribute 8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Attribute 9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Attribute 10</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```